# Is `node-sqlite each function load all queries into memory, or it use stream/pipe from hard-disk

Tags: node.js, node-sqlite3

I want to handle 10,000,000 rows

This is my code:

```
stmt.each('select * from very_big_table',function(err,rows,next){
      console.log('This can take 2 seconds'
})
```

The question is: It will eat all my RAM, or it will read from hard-drive row after row?

Answer (score 1):

I've just recently created this helper class to handle streaming:

```
import { ReadableTyped } from '@naturalcycles/nodejs-lib'
import { Database, Statement } from 'sqlite'
import { Readable } from 'stream'

/**
 * Based on: https://gist.github.com/rmela/a3bed669ad6194fb2d9670789541b0c7
 */
export class SqliteReadable<T = any> extends Readable implements ReadableTyped<T> {
  constructor(private stmt: Statement) {
    super( { objectMode: true } );

    // might be unnecessary
    // this.on( 'end', () => {
    //   console.log(`SQLiteStream end`)
    //   void this.stmt.finalize()
    // })
  }

  static async create<T = any>(db: Database, sql: string): Promise<SqliteReadable<T>> {
    const stmt = await db.prepare(sql)
    return new SqliteReadable<T>(stmt)
  }

  /**
   * Necessary to call it, otherwise this error might occur on `db.close()`:
   * SQLITE_BUSY: unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups
   */
  async close(): Promise<void> {
    await this.stmt.finalize()
  }

  // count = 0 // use for debugging

  override async _read(): Promise<void> {
    // console.log(`read ${++this.count}`) // debugging
    try {
      const r = await this.stmt.get<T>()
      this.push(r || null)
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err) // todo: check if it's necessary
      this.emit('error', err)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both. `statement.each` will not use any extra memory if the function is fast and synchronous, however with asynchronous functions it will start all asynchronous processing as fast as it can load the data from disk, and this will eat up all your RAM.

As is also said in the issue you posted here https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/686 it is possible to get your desired behavior using `Statement.get()`. `Statement.get()` without any parameters will fetch the next row. So you can implement your own async version like this:

```js
function asyncEach(db, sql, parameters, eachCb, doneCb) {
  let stmt;

  let cleanupAndDone = err => {
    stmt.finalize(doneCb.bind(null, err));
  };

  stmt = db.prepare(sql, parameters, err => {
    if (err) {
      return cleanupAndDone(err);
    }

    let next = err => {
      if (err) {
        return cleanupAndDone(err);
      }

      return stmt.get(recursiveGet);
    };

    // Setup recursion
    let recursiveGet = (err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        return cleanupAndDone(err);
      }

      if (!row) {
        return cleanupAndDone(null);
      }

      // Call the each callback which must invoke the next callback
      return eachCb(row, next);
    }

    // Start recursion
    stmt.get(recursiveGet);
  });
}
```

Note, slightly different syntax than the built in `Statement.each`, errors are only sent to the last callback and no support for optional parameters.

Also note that this is slower than the normal `Statement.each` function, which can be improved by issuing multiple `get` calls so the next row is waiting when `next` is invoked, but it is much harder to follow that code.

Example for using the snippet:

```js
let rowCount = 0;
asyncEach(db, 'SELECT * from testtable', [], (row, next) => {
  assert.isObject(row);
  rowCount++;
  return next();
}, err => {
  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
  assert.equal(rowCount, TEST_ROW_COUNT);
  done();
});
```